# My question on Advanced English Grammar?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

If my question were deleted, would a moderator please repost the the input? I ask about this now because I only now just lighted upon [this answer on `subject-dependent inversion`](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/40402/8712), which cites 
[*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*](http://www.amazon.ca/The-Cambridge-Grammar-English-Language/dp/0521431468)  by Rodney Huddleston, Apr 15 2002. I haven't read it so I don't know if it's the exemplar of my search, but at least I found a possibility.
Yet the problem persists: how do you learn more about such books and such topics?

**Pros:** It seems to cohere with my objectives because `subject-dependent inversion`seems advanced, as do all [these types of inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English) and [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29) seem, yet does periodically figure in literary texts.

**Cons:** 1. So I worry that on average, CGEL's topics may emerge too abstract or esoteric.

2. At 1860 pages, reading it may prove onerous or stark, though I never intended to read a grammar book in one continuous instance.

Comment: I don't see any deleted questions on your ELL account. Can you explain a bit further what you're asking? Thanks!

Comment: In re: "how to learn about such books": CGEL is currently considered *the* grammar of the English language. Even on ELL and ELU, which are populated mostly by enthusiasts and not professional linguists, you were sure to trip over it at *some* point. But it *is* written by and intended for professional linguists and it certainly will be too long, too broad, and in many ways too abstract to learn English from. That is not what it's designed for, and trying to use it that way will be a long hard road indeed.

Comment: And I've expressed this to you before, but it's worth repeating: the way to achieve your goal of speaking fluent, fluid, flawless English is *practice*. There is no other way, unfortunately, and no hidden shortcut in some dusty tome at the back of a secret library that no one has told you about. This is as true for native speakers as for EFL.

Comment: @WendiKidd Thanks. That's strange. I'm certain that I asked a question about Advanced English Grammar in the past on ELL? I think that it was closed, though. What would've happened to the question?

Comment: @DanBron Thank you. I accept your suggestion on spoken English. With this question, I intended to learn about written English, though, especially the grammar of grammar, syntax, etc... For instance, had I not lighted upon that answer above, I would've asked about that inversion anew here. Yet had I read a book that broached this, I would've been prepared, and even maybe been the answer? I sense that I'm missing the advanced grammar knowledge, prerequisite for and prevalent in, the texts about which I've been asking here. Does this help?

Comment: @Law: My comment was directed at using (specifically, the functional impossibility of using) a comprehensive grammar like CGEL to learn English. The warning was not intended to be understood as restricted to spoken English, and by the same token the advice that years of practice is the only path to fluency applies equally to writing English. It's a bitter pill, I know, but it's true.

Comment: I do remember the question, but I can't find it either. I remember having a discussion about whether a linguistics text was appropriate. If it was closed, the Community bot may have deleted it automatically if it met certain conditions.

Comment: @DanBron: Thank you again for your advice. Ar there really no books at all about this, even something that helps slightly? I want to avoid swallowing that bitter pill for now.

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you again! Yes, I remember your comment as well.

Comment: @Law There are *plenty* of books, of course. But no shortcuts. I can't recommend any specific books, for a variety of reasons (one being, IIRC from that previous question on learning grammar, even *you* don't know quite what it is you're looking for), and anyway, my opinion is that the answer lies in *many* books, not any specific one. You need exposure and practice, so English becomes intuitive rather than deliberate and conscious. To that end, maybe what you should read is novels or biographies or whatever you are interested in its own right, rather than endless grammars and guides.

Comment: @Law [cont'd] It's also worth repeating, though I know you've heard it before, that a private English tutor who can *learn* what you know and what you struggle with, and tailor a curriculum specifically for your needs, would probably provide the highest acceleration; but learning English would have to be important enough to you to spend the money.